# Firestore - Managing User Sessions by revoking tokens

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm looking into being able to manage user sessions - e.g. revoke tokens for bad actors and not let them to access data immediately (instead of after an hour/token lifetime).

In the guides it mentions being able to do comparisons vs stored "revoke time" in Security Rules. But it only mentions Firebase Realtime Database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_database_rules

> Save the refresh token revocation timestamp. This is needed to track ID token revocation via Firebase rules. This allows for efficient checks within the database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.auth_time > (root.child('metadata').child(auth.uid).child('revokeTime').val() || 0)",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.auth_time > (root.child('metadata').child(auth.uid).child('revokeTime').val() || 0)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key here is **`auth.token.auth_time`**

I tried to use this in Firestore Security Rules but it [doesn't seem to be available](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth).

**Is this not possible in Firestore?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebe had you were correct in needing to put `request` before `request.auth.token.auth_time`.

Even though its not shown in the documentation it seems to be there.

I had to create my own document during `AuthOnCreate` for each user when they first sign up so that there were fields for `revoke_time` (the designated key I made up, you can choose your own).

Then I stored these for each user in a `revoked_tokens` collection and could compare against in security rules.

```
function notRevoked() {
      return request.auth.token.auth_time > get(/databases/$(db)/documents/revoked_tokens/$(currentUser().uid)).data.revoke_time;
}
```

Firestore seems to be different that RTDB because you can't just use a default value of `|| 0`. You actually need to have a value in the Firestore to compare against. I think this is because [Firestore get() functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.html#.get) return `null`.

> non-null `rules.firestore.Resource` the document, or `null` if it does not exist.

So if the document doesn't exist and you try to drill down into the `get().data.someKey` it will just error out and blow up your Security Rule. It would be like trying to do `null.data.someKey`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this works, in Firestore you have to set these rules on collections or documents.

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /collection/{documentId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.auth_time > (root.child('metadata').child(auth.uid).child('revokeTime').val() || 0);
     }
   }
 }
```

I will try it myself if i find the time.